# Recursive function to replace integer in arthmetic expression

Tags: recursion

I need to write recursive function Repl 
takes as input an expression in e in Expr and returns an expression in Expr
wherein each number is replaced by the number 1.
For example, if e is the expression
((((9 + 5) ∗ 2) ∗ (2 + (4 ∗ 6))))
then Repl(e) is the expression
((((1 + 1) ∗ 1) ∗ (1 + (1 ∗ 1))))

Can anybody help me how to go about this?
Iterative one is easy to write but how to write it recursively?

Comment: have you thought above a recursive function where each successive recursion returns a shorter substring?

Comment: Do you expect multi-digit numbers?

Comment: No I do not. I just want a pseudo code.

Comment: @cctan I am not able to think on it. Can you help giving a simpler example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you would want a recursive solution for this problem, but the solution is relatively straightforward. Here is pseudocode:

```
string replace(string s, bool seenDigit) {
    if (s == "") {
        // The string is empty : we are done
        return "";
    }
    if (s[0] is digit) {
        if (seenDigit) {
            // This is a second, third, etc. digit in a multi-digit chain
            // It has been replaced with "1" already, so we cut it out
            return replace(s.substring(1), true);
        } else {
            // This is the first digit in a chain of one or more digits
            // Replace it with "1", and tell the next level that we've
            // done the replacement already
            return "1"+replace(s.substring(1), true);
        }
    } else {
        // Non-digits do not get replaced
        return s[0] + replace(s.substring(1), false);
    }
}
```

`s[0]` means the first character; `string+string` denotes concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This may sound silly but what does replace(s.substring(1),false) do ? I didnt get why the argument 1 in s.substring?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention: `substring(1)` means "string with its initial character chopped off". This function is used this way in .NET, specifically in C#, and in Java.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any sources where I can practice more on recursion and be comfortable with it?

Comment: @Maxwell I learned recursion from [Dijkstra's classic book](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/programmiersprachen/artikel/EWD-notes-structured.pdf): scroll down to page 72 to see a very nice treatment of the 8-queen problem. There is also a good [pair of articles on TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=recursionPt1) explaining practical uses of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Making @dasblinkenlight's solution tail recursive:

```
string replace(string sToGo, string sSoFar, bool inNumber) {
    if (sToGo == "") {
        return sSoFar;
    }
    if (sToGo[0] is digit) {
        if (isNumber) {
            return replace(sSoFar, sToGo.substring(1), true);
        } else {
            return replace(sSoFar+"1", sToGo.substring(1), true);
        }
    } else {
        return replace(sSoFar+s[0], sToGo.substring(1), false);
    }
}
```

Notice that every return is either a direct value (the base case) or directly returns what a recursive call gives back.  This means the program doesn't need to keep track of the recursive calls, because there's nothing to do with the value being returned other than returning it up the chain, which means (if the interpreter takes advantage of it) that the primary downside to using recursion (the overhead of the stack) can be eliminated.

Comment: You may want to mention why tail recursion is desirable (and it is certainly desirable).